# Reinstalled 11.04 but now it looks like 10.10

Tags: 11.04, unity

I had to reinstall ubuntu 11.04 but now the unity sidebar is gone and it looks like I installed 10.10 but when checking my current version it does say 11.04.Does anyone know how I can get the unity sidebar and all the other stuff from 11.04 back?

Answer (score 5):

You're likely in the "classic mode". You should be able to log out and select "Ubuntu" from the login screen to login into Unity.

If you don't get Unity then it probably needs to have the right drivers installed, you can make sure you have the right drivers by running "Additional Drivers" from the preferences menu.

[image]

After it goes through all that you should be able to log into Unity.